# Docker image with Kafka and Zookepper

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I´m trying to run Kafka and Zookepper using Docker, following the steps defined here: https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka

But after running, just as described, the docker container

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active\`` --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
```

I´m not able to publish anything and if I make a `wget localhost:9092` I receive empty response.

I don't understand what for are the exports, mentioned in the documentation.

Any idea if I´m doing something wrong?

Also if somebody know a better image please let me know.

Comment: You should specify how you ran that image

Comment: I update my question, I´m very noob in Kafka and I´m just following the steps

Comment: Try these, then https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks I´m gonna read this, anyway the docker image documentation could be a little bit better. Install Kafka and zookepper by brew in my Mac was far more easy

Comment: The Confluent documentation is great, IMO. Just the Kafka and Zookeeper aren't in the same image

Comment: Not mention what you gave me but the Spotify/Kafka docker documentation

Comment: Oh, right. Plus it's running a Kafka version that's about 5 releases ago, and repository hasn't been updated in over a year

Comment: say no more, I´ll go with the images that you sent me. The documentation is so so so much better. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka doesn't run HTTP server. Port 9092 over wget doesn't do anything

You need to describe the topics using the `kafka-topics` command, which can be found in the documentation, which will connect to Zookeeper over the port 2181.

Something like

```
docker exec kafka-zk kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

If you wanted to make an HTTP request, you would need Kafka REST proxy, which I believe is only in the Confluent images

Comment: Sorry like I said, I´m very noob, could you please can refer some documentation about how to configure that?. If I connect by bash to the docker container the command kafka-topics does not exist

Comment: It should exist, but it's not on the PATH. I've not used the Spotify image, so I don't know where Kafka is installed

Comment: Yeah I guess that´s why in the documetation make the exports of KAKFA, but it does not work

Comment: I'm not sure what exports you're referring to